# Binding keys using org.eclipse.ui.binding

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I am trying to introduce a shortcut key(<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd>) to our customized  editor to format the content.

I've implememented the following changes.

1. Added changes to plugin xml by adding key extension with definition Id/schema/context.
2. Implemented Action by extending TextEditorAction class as below.

   ```
   @Override
   public void run() {
       this.doOperation(ISourceViewer.FORMAT);
   }
   ```
3. Implemented one Formatter class by implementing `IContentFormatter`.
4. Passed the above Formatter class to our cutsomized `sourceVIewConfiguration` (extends `SourceViewerConfiguration`) class by overriding `getContentFormatter`.
5. overrided `createActions()` API inside our customized editor class which extends `TextEditor`.

For some reason my shortcut key is not working. I put a debug point inside my action class and noticed the controller is not going there when i press on the shortcut key.

I also noticed that the newly created key is not displayed under preferences -> keys list.

Can somebody provide pointers or example to resolve the issue.

## plugin.xml entries:

```xml
 <key
            commandId="com.language.javascripteditor.XJSFormatAction"
            schemeId="myScheme"
            sequence="M1+M2+z"/>
      <scheme
            id="myScheme"
            name="myScheme">
      </scheme>
```

## Formatter class:

```java
public class JavaScriptEditorFormatter implements IContentFormatter {

    @Override
    public void format(IDocument document, IRegion region) {
        try {
            String content =document.get(region.getOffset(), region.getLength());
            String formatted = new JSBeautifier().js_beautify(content,null);
            document.replace(region.getOffset(), region.getLength(), formatted);
        } catch (BadLocationException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public IFormattingStrategy getFormattingStrategy(String contentType) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

}
```

Added a new property file for customized schema with the name plugin_customization.ini and with the content as below
`org.eclipse.ui/KEY_CONFIGURATION_ID=myScheme`

Command section inside plugin.xml

```xml
<command
            defaultHandler="com.cisco.nm.workflowbuilder.language.javascripteditor.XJSFormatAction"
    id="com.language.javascripteditor.XJSFormatAction"
    name="%action.label.format.xjs">
</command>
```

Instead of a handler I have written an `Action` class. Please let me know if this approach does not work

Comment: Show us the `key` binding in the plugin.xml. What context is it using? What command id? How have you defined the command id and handler?

Comment: <key
            commandId="com.language.javascripteditor.XJSFormatAction"
            schemeId="myScheme"
            sequence="M1+M2+f"/>
      <scheme
            id="myScheme"
            name="myScheme">
      </scheme>

Comment: Please [edit] you question when adding extra information. How is the command `com.cisco.nm.workflowbuilder.language.javascripteditor.XJSFormatAction` defined - show us the `org.eclipse.ui.commands` definition, Show us the `org.eclipse.ui.handlers` definition for the handler. Using a different scheme means you will have to activate that. More likely you want a context id you activate in the editor,

Comment: i am implementing using org.eclipse.ui.binding with Action class , I am not using the handler approach

Comment: Key bindings only work with commands and handlers you can't go directly to an action. I suggest you look at the `org.eclipse.jdt.ui` plugin to see how it does this.

Comment: Do i need to implement handler class along with the action class

Comment: Actually I think you can get directly to an action from a command using the old, deprecated, `org.eclipse.ui.actionSets` extension point. Otherwise a handler is required,

Comment: i am able to bind the key finally with the help of org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.BasicTextEditorActionContributor entry inside plugin.xml of my editor along with few other changes inside my Action class.

Answer (score 0):

1.Added contributor class to extension of the existing editor.
2.Created command with an id for format.eg: com.javascript.text.format
3.written Action class with format method

```
@Override
    public void run() {
        this.doOperation(ISourceViewer.FORMAT);
    }
```

4. plugin xml entry

```
  <key
            commandId="com.javascript.text.format"
            schemeId="org.eclipse.ui.defaultAcceleratorConfiguration"
            sequence="M1+M2+F"/>
```

5. Overriden the createActions() .Inside this method instantiated the Action class and setActionDefinitionId.

Comment: But i encountered new problem. Already there is a keybing with same keyboard commands(ctrl+shift+F). Now i need leads to override that command when i open this editor.Basically need pointers to resolve the conflicts. I tried with different schemaId but that did not helped me.